# isset() with dynamic property names

Tags: php, oop

Why does `isset()` not work when the property names are in variables?

```
$Object = new stdClass();
$Object->tst = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2);

$tst = 'tst'; $one = 'one';
var_dump( $Object, isset( $Object->tst['one'] ), isset( $Object->$tst[ $one ] ) );
```

outputs the following:

```
object(stdClass)#39 (1) {
  ["tst"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["one"]=>
    int(1)
    ["two"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
bool(true)
bool(false) // was expecting true here..
```

---

**Edit:** went on toying around with the code, and found out that

```
var_dump( $Object->$tst['one'] );
```

outputs a Notice:

```
E_NOTICE: Undefined property: stdClass::$t
```

So I think the problem is that the `$tst[...]` part is evaluated in 'string mode' (evaluating to the first character in the string; in this case "t"), before going onto fetching the property from the object;

```
var_dump( $tst, $tst['one'] ); // string(3) "tst" string(1) "t"
```

---

**Solution:** is to put braces around the variable name (`$this->{$tst}`), to tell the interpreter to retrieve its *value* first, and then evaluate the `[...]` part:

```
var_dump( $Object->{$tst}['one'] ); // int(1) yay!
```

Comment: Y u doing such cruel things to poor `isset()`? What's it ever done to you? (Seriously though, good question, I'm baffled!)

Comment: What does `var_dump($Object->$tst)` display?

Comment: The issue is just operator precedence here. `[]` over `->` due to variable as attribute name.

Comment: I think the property `$Object->$tst['one']` does not exist. Try to echo it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding braces around the property name...

```
isset( $Object->{$tst}[ $one ] );
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/IEPCEbiW).

Comment: It works! You are a hero. Care to explain what exactly is happening here? :)

Comment: @Rijk Just figuring it out myself. My hunch is operator precedence, though PHP [doesn't define](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) the precedence for `->` (though it does define the array subscript `[` operator).

Comment: `var_dump( $Object->$tst['one'] );` outputs `E_NOTICE: Undefined property: stdClass::$t`.. Maybe the `$tst[...]` part is being evaluated 'as string' first?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question :)

Went on toying around with the code, and found out that

```
var_dump( $Object->$tst['one'] );
```

outputs a Notice:

```
E_NOTICE: Undefined property: stdClass::$t
```

So I think the problem is that the $tst[...] part is evaluated in 'string mode' (evaluating to the first character in the string; in this case "t"), before going onto fetching the property from the object;

```
var_dump( $tst, $tst['one'] ); // string(3) "tst" string(1) "t"
```

The solution is to put braces around the variable name (`$this->{$tst}`), to tell the interpreter to retrieve its *value* first, and then evaluate the `[...]` part.

```
var_dump( $Object->{$tst}['one'] );
```

I'm going to accept alex's answer, as it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks everyone!

Comment: And now in PHP 7, they appeared to have finally changed this behaviour.